# document and iframe in just one selector

Tags: jquery, iframe, binding, jquery-selectors

I am currently injecting an `iframe` and binding a `keyevent` both to the `document` and the `iframe`.

**Can I select both the iFrame and the document in one row?**
<sub>notice the iframe must have `.contents()` after the selector</sub>

```
// wait for iframe to load
$('iframe#iframe').load(function() {

    // event bind to document
    $(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
        console.log("runs document");
    });

    // event bind to iframe
    $(this).contents().bind('keydown', function(e) {
        console.log("runs iframe");
    });     

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/), like this:

```
$(this).contents().add(document).keydown(function(e) {
    console.log("runs in both");
});
```

This takes the iframe contents then just adds the `document` on the returned jQuery object as well, resulting in both being having the handler to their `keydown` event.

Comment: Took you about 2m to solve something I was running around for more than 20! ;) 7 more minutes to accept. Thks Nick.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
// wait for iframe to load
$('iframe#iframe').load(function() {

    // event bind to iframe
    $(this).contents().add(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
        console.log("runs iframe and document");
    });     

});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/add/

Comment: There's no reason to wrap a jQuery object in a jQuery object :)